# NullReferenceException in viewing the logged UserName

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm trying to make a simple Login Page and Storing the logged user using `SetAuthCookie` but i'm getting an error `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code`. I'm still new to this so I'm still not familiar to Cookies Authenticating

I got null **error** in this line

```
<h1> @Model.UserName </h1>
```

Here's my code :

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using logUser.Functions;
using logUser.Models;

namespace logUser.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserInfo employeeUser = new UserInfo();
        employeeUser.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

**LoginController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using logUser.Models;
using logUser.Functions;

namespace logUser.Controllers
{
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoLogin(logUser.Models.UserInfo u)
    {
        Employee bal = new Employee();
        if (bal.IsValidUser(u))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.UserName, true);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Login");
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Login.cshtml**

```
@model logUser.Models.UserInfo
@{
Layout = null;
}

<h2>Login</h2>

<div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("DoLogin", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.LabelFor(c => c.UserName)

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName)



<br />

@Html.LabelFor(c => c.Password)

@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)

<br />


<input type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" value="Login" />

}

</div>
```

**Employee.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using logUser.Models;

namespace logUser.Functions
{
public class Employee
{
    public bool IsValidUser(UserInfo u)
    {
        if (u.UserName == "Admin" && u.Password == "Admin")
        {

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using logUser.Models
@model UserInfo
@{ var myMessage = "Hello World"; }
<p> Hi!  @myMessage </p>
<h1> @Model.UserName </h1>
```

**NOTE :** I already configure the Web.config

Thanks

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is a common situation for beginner programmers. The link provided should help you understand the problem. Then use the debugger to find what/where/when you have a variable that is `null`.

Comment: Where occurs `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @goodeinstein I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: When You first run app this merohd Login return empty view olso method Index return empty view - empty view like view witout model. This line `UserInfo employeeUser = new UserInfo();
        employeeUser.UserName = User.Identity.Name; return View()` do nothing - return empty view

Comment: Thank you for the tips but how do I display the `UserName` of the logged user? also is my SetAuthCookies are correct? Thank you

Comment: It is next question, ask on SO or find on SO.

Comment: @goodeinstein ahh Okay thanks :)

Comment: @goodeinstein I already made a new question. can you help me in this one. please [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010085/how-to-display-data-from-setauthcookies)