# How to display data from SetAuthCookies

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm having a trouble to display the logged User save by using `SetAuthCookies` how do I retrieve it? I'm still new to this.

Heres my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using logUser.Models;
using logUser.Functions;

namespace logUser.Controllers
{
public class LoginController : Controller
{
// GET: Login
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoLogin(logUser.Models.UserInfo u)
{
    Employee bal = new Employee();
    if (bal.IsValidUser(u))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.UserName, true);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
}
}
}
```

**Note :** I already configure the Web.config
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You create a `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` to retrive user name you can call

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

or

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

**More info...**

[Getting the current user id (not name) using forms authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241298/getting-the-current-user-id-not-name-using-forms-authentication)